# ACPI bios error bug could not start system

Tags: ubuntu, boot

I am new to linux. I am using Hp laptop. I have two OS ubuntu 20.04 LTS and windows 8. Few days ago I tried to install one software, system hang. So, I restarted my laptop. windows is working fine but I could not boot in ubuntu. How to repair the system rather than reinstallation?[image: error can be seen in the image]

Comment: 1. Which HP laptop, they made more than one. 2. what software were you installing to cause the *system hang*

Comment: Probably related: [VMX (outside TXT) : disabled by bios](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1297433/vmx-outside-txt-disabled-by-bios)

Comment: Ignore the ACPI errors, the standard & implementation is all broken and is unlikely to be the problem here.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please don't post [screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). They are often difficult to read and the content will not show up in search engine results. Instead, paste it into the question using code formatting (although I'm aware that this requires type-copying on your side).

Comment: @AdminBee if the system doesn't boot, how the user is supposed to extract the text? And these errors are not indicative of anything. The issue is elsewhere.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov As I stated: _"I'm aware that this requires type-copying on your side"_. And if these errors are not indicative of anything, you might as well edit the screenshot out considering that you have the necessary reputation to do so.

Comment: My edits won't make anything more clear :-(  I remember leaving a comment about removing `quiet` from the kernel boot option, booting, taking a picture and posting it here but it seems to have disappeared.

Comment: Please try following this: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelBoot

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov _"My edits won't make anything more clear"_ ... I don't know - if they remove distracting information, the question may well be clearer.